# How to run wp_insert_post() & wpdb on the background?

Tags: wpdb, wp-cron, wp-insert-post, cron

I have created a code to fetch data from a remote API then echo certain data & import those data into a **post type** using `wp_insert_post()` & post meta** using `wpdb->query()`.

Here's my current code:

```
$imdbid = $_GET['id'];
$string = file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=".$imdbid."&apikey=API_KEY_HEREKEYVALUE");
$json = json_decode($string, true);

if( $json['Response'] === "True" ){    

    //METADATA
    $dataID = $json['imdbID'];
    $dataTitle = $json['Title'];
    $dataYear = $json['Year'];

    $dbdata = array(
        'post_title'    => $dataID,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'datadb', 
        'post_author'   => 1
                );
          
        
    if( $dbid = wp_insert_post( $dbdata ) ){

        //METADATA PRINT
        echo $dataID;
        echo $dataTitle;
        echo $dataYear;



        $statement = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta
        (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
        VALUES
        ('".$dbID."', 'ztdb_imdb_id', '%s'), 
        ('".$dbID."', 'ztdb_title', '%s'),
        ('".$dbID."', 'ztdb_year', '%s');";
      
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare($statement, $dataID, $dataTitle, $dataYear);
        $wpdb->query($sql); 

    }
          
}
```

Right now, if i use just these codes, the page would not stop loading until `wp_insert_post()` and `wpdb` is completed. Is there any way I could run both of them on the background so the user's page load is not affected when visiting the page and the **$dataID, $dataTitle, and $dataYear** is echoed/displayed immediately?

Answer (score 1):

> page load is not affected [...] and the //METADATA is echoed/displayed immediately?

With your current setup, that is not possible. In order to display immediately, you need the data. To get the data, you need to wait.

Possible solutions are:

1. Fetch the data before (e.g. via Cron) and populate the DB with the info. -> No need to fetch it live, but you might not know, which `id`s to get and which not to.
2. Fetch the data asynchronous (e.g. via calling a REST endpoint in the template). -> Page will load fast, but parts are missing and rendered later. No need to pre-fetch the data though.